# swift numberOfRowsInSection from dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Hello everybody this is my first post.
I'm trying to show dynamic data in a `TableView`: I have the data in a `Dictionary` like this `var dizionarioComuni : Dictionary<Character, Array<ComuneModel>> = [:]`
The object ComuneModel is a custom model whit data as nomeComune, numAbitanti and so on 
In the `TableView` i wrote this code to obtain the numbers of the sections and it works

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //tot valori nel dictionary
    dizionarioComuni.count
}
```

The keys of the dictionary are Charachters because i want use these keys as title of the section. 
The question is: how can i get the `numberOfRowsInSection` in the method of the table view ? the signature of the method is this

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

anf take an integer but my keys are charachters. I try to access to all  the keys of the dictionary with this code

```
var keys = dizionarioComuni.keys
```

I can iterate over the keys but then how can i access from a specific key at the object list (of ComuniModel) at a specific index (the section: Int) that is the parameter of the method?

i search for similar question but the answer doesn't talk about this case.
thanks a lot

Comment: Please post your actual data of dictonary.

Answer (score 1):

Swift dictionaries are unordered, so you need to maintain a separate list of sorted keys and use that to access your data.

```
var sortedKeys = dizionarioComuni.keys.sort()
```

Then `numberOfRowsInSection` becomes:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dizionarioComuni[sortedKeys[section]]?.count ?? 0
}
```

Note: any time your list of keys changes, you will need to reload the data in your table.

---

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var sortedKeys = [Character]() {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != sortedKeys {
                // reload tableView
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    var dizionarioComuni = [Character: [ComuneModel]]() {
        didSet {
            sortedKeys = dizionarioComuni.keys.sort()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error index out of range, but your code is correct and compile i'm  trying to understand what is the problem thanks a lot.

Comment: Check out updated answer.  It maintains the list of sorted keys by using the `didSet` property observer.

Comment: hi first of all thanks for your time @vacawama . But the line of code { var dizionarioComuni it gives an error i'm trying to understand..

Comment: in my code there is a var named dizionarioComuni but in this var is stored the Dictionary values.

Comment: Is `dizionarioComuni` a property of your viewController?  Where does it live?  You said the data is dynamic.  How does it get updated?

Comment: i get the data from an http call that returns a json. I store the values from the json in a dictionary. The values are dynamic because the first time i download i don't know the number of the items. The sequence is 1) i download the data, 2) i store the data in a dictionary. In the dictionary the key is a letter (the first letter of the property nomeComune of the ComuneModel object) and the values for every key is an array of objects ComuneModel. Once i download the data they doesn't change. Then i would show the items in a class that implements  UITableViewController in a way as Contacts App

Comment: the data are downloaded in another class called DataManager, this class is a Singleton.

Comment: Where is `dizionarioComuni`? I guessed from your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` that it was a property of your `UITableViewController` subclass.

Comment: Where is the code that sets the value of `dizinarinoComuni`?

Comment: dizionarioComuni is a var in the Singleton DataManager. I simplified the code to be more clear. But i get the values with this code  DataManager.sharedInstance.dizionarioComuni.... , i call the method that download the data in the viewDidLoad  DataManager.sharedInstance.downloadJSONCmn(url: zoneOrderByComune)

Comment: You call the method that downloads the data in the `viewDidLoad` of which class? Your tableViewController?  How do you know when the data has been loaded (I assume it is loaded with an asynchronous call)?  Your tableView needs to reload the data once the data is ready.  It can compute the sortedKeys at that time, or the Singleton which holds the dictionary can also keep the updated sortedKeys.